# Unicode Compiler error on simple function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Sigh

I am working with the Microsoft Visual Express C++ IDE. I have recently transitioned from DevC++ to this IDE.

**I have a function that works perfectly in DevC++ but in MSVC++ it wont compile because of Unicode (I think?). What do I need to change to get my function to compile?**

See the commented code line for the compiler error I get

```
map <string, string> GetEvironmentVariablesEx()
{
   map <string, string> envVariables;
   char* environVar = GetEnvironmentStrings();  // Compile error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LPWCH' to 'char *'
   char* pos        = strchr( environVar, '\0' );

   // Skip over the "=::=::\0" of the environVar string
   if ( pos != NULL ) { environVar = ++pos; pos = strchr( environVar, '\0' ); }
   else return envVariables;

   while ( true )
   {
       char* delim    = strchr( environVar, '=' );
       if ( delim == NULL )
            break;

       string variable = string( environVar, strlen(environVar)-strlen(delim) );
       string value    = string( ++delim );

       envVariables.insert( pair<string, string>(variable, value) );
       environVar = ++pos;

       // find the "\0\0" that identifies the end of environVar
       if ( pos != NULL && *pos == 0 ) { break; }

       pos = strchr( environVar, '\0' );
   }

   FreeEnvironmentStrings( environVar ); 
   return envVariables;       
}
```

PS: Because this application is compiled in Unicode, does that mean that it will work on both ANSII computers & UNICODE computers - so my app will able to be run internationally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your project is a UNICODE build and you using ANSI strings, first thing to do is replacing your char variables to TCHAR and try again.

And as @David Heffernan, aptly suggested, you will have to switch to wstring and aptly change the library functions from standard library which you use.

Comment: not enough just to use TCHAR. You have to switch to wstring and change which std lib functions you call too.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yup was just about to edit! +1 for me for you on that.

Comment: This will be a good start and allow you to compile as ANSI or Unicode. You shall also need to use the 't'-variants of the string library functions, such as `_tcschr()` instead of `strchr`.

Comment: The TCHAR is just for code that should continue to be usable for both `char` and `wchar_t`, enabling its use on various old Windows versions. If that is not required, just select one of them and be happy with that.

Answer (score 3):

Visual C++ is attempting to compile your program with support for Unicode. Under the hood, this is done by `#define`-ing the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros. This, in turn, causes your program to use the Unicode variants of the Win32 functions.

Each Win32 function (that takes or returns a string) has two variants. For example, `GetEnvironmentStrings` is actually two functions: `GetEnvironmentStringsA` and `GetEnvironmentStringsW`. `GetEnvironmentStrings` resolves to one of these, depending on whether or not the `UNICODE` macro is defined.

So, your program is being compiled for Unicode and the compiler can't figure out how to take the result of (Unicode) `GetEnvironmentStringsW` (which is a `LPWCH` -- actually `WCHAR *`) and put it into (ANSI) `std::string`.

You can do one (or a combination) of the following:

1. Convert your entire program to Unicode (start using `std::wstring`).
2. Use `GetEnvironmentStringsA` explicitly.
3. Recompile for non-Unicode instead.
4. Make use of the `TCHAR` support in Windows. You'll need to [define a `tstring` type](http://rioki.org/2010/09/24/tstring.html).

This is not an exhaustive list.

Re:

> Because this application is compiled in Unicode, does that mean that it will work on both ANSII computers & UNICODE computers - so my app will able to be run internationally?

Computers aren't ANSI or Unicode. Operating Systems are. The last version of Windows that didn't support Unicode was Windows 3.11 for Workgroups.

That said, just compiling for Unicode doesn't make your app able to be run internationally. It'll work just fine, but Unicode only covers character sets. You still need to worry about translation, date and time formats, number formats, different calendars. There's a lot more to internationalization, localization and globalization than just enabling Unicode support.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, is it value C++ to do this? GetEvironmentVariablesEx()[L"USERNAME"].c_str(); or do I have to store the map in a variable before I try to access a key value pair?

Comment: @user you're meant to accept the best answer. That's this one.

Answer (score 2):

You are compiling the app targetting Unicode strings but declaring ANSI string variables. If you want Unicode then you need to use wide chars, `wstring` and the corresponding string handling routines in the standard library.

If you aren't ready to tackle that change yet then change the project options from Unicode to MBCS which is the slightly counter intuitive way to get an ANSI build.

Answer (score 0):

It is not if your program will run correctly on different Windows boxes or not - it about conversions made by Windows. A Windows API that takes one or more *string* as argument, it would have 2 versions: ANSI and Unicode. Though not all functions have 2 variants (like ReadDirectoryChangesW, which is Unicode-only).

When you call a ANSI version, Windows need to copy that ANSI-string into Unicode string. Yes, it needs memory allocation, conversion of 1-byte ANSI characters into 2-byte Unicode characters. And if that function is giving one or more strings as *output*, it would need to convert Unicode to ANSI.

This, obviously would be time and memory consuming, and make your program slow. Moreover, many of ANSI versions would/may modify the ANSI-string passed, and it would require you **not** to pass string constants. If you pass string-constants (like hard-coded executable-path to **CreateProcessA**), it would lead to some Win32 memory exception.

Therefore it is better to convert all ANSI projects into Unicode.

PS: It is frustating to use _T, _TEXT or even **L** for strings. Why can't VC++ compiler supports an option to treat all **"strings"** as **L"strings"** ? :[

Comment: Why can't VC++ compiler supports an option to treat all "strings" as L"strings"? Well that would then be some language other than C++.

Comment: Not convincing. When 'auto' is part of C++ language, which seems like 'var' (which isnt!). Then why not compiler option to treat strings as Unicode strings?  In VC++, there are many options under 'Language' - "Treat strings as Unicode" can be put!

Comment: The rules of the language are well defined. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I again beg to differ, 'Disable Language Extension' is for MS Compiler. The non-constant array size support is by GCC. Both aren't 100% compliant against "well defined language rules".

Comment: all these vendor specific extensions are a ruddy nightmare to work with